# Getting 400 Bad Request when trying to add a user to an AD group using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am dealing with the extremely strange issue. The code that I built worked just fine one year ago, but now it doesn't.

I am trying to add a user to an AD group but get 400 bad request error. What can I do to fix it? Should I switch to a certain version for ActiveDirectory package?

Thank you in advance. Here is my function

```
public static async Task<string> AddGroupMember(string accessToken, string groupId, string memberId)
{
    var status = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        string endpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/" + groupId + "/members/$ref";
        string queryParameter = "";

        // pass body data 
        var keyOdataId = "@odata.id";
        var valueODataId = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/" + memberId;

        var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyOdataId, valueODataId)
        };
        var jsonData = $@"{{ ""{keyOdataId}"": ""{valueODataId}"" }}";
        var body = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpoint + queryParameter))
            {
                request.Content = body;
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
                        status = "Member added to Group";
                    else
                        status = $"Unable to add Member to Group: {response.StatusCode}";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        status = $"Error adding Member to Group: {ex.Message}";
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: What is the content in the 400 error response ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I tried to add users that already existed in a group. The issue of duplicate users caused the 400 Bad Request error